# Dockerode works with node, but not via Webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, webpack

I am trying to write a web application that can start a Docker container.
Therefore, I am using the *dockerode* module. 
The short module looks like this:

```
//index.js

var Docker = require('dockerode');
var docker = new Docker({socketPath: '/var/run/docker.sock'});
docker.buildImage({
    /*
    Building image over here...
    */
});
```

Running this JavaScript file with node like this:

```
node index.js
```

Works just fine. My local Docker installation will build a new image and afterwards create a new container. Finally, this container will be started.

However, now I am trying to add this module to a web application by using *Webpack*.

But now the problem is: When using the *webpack.config.js* property

```
target: 'web'
```

Webpack successfully builds the file, but when opening the website I receive this issue:

```
Uncaught TypeError: stat is not a function
    at loop (gen.js:27528)
    at onnextentry (gen.js:27640)
    at Object.exports.pack (gen.js:27643)
    at Docker.buildImage (gen.js:22180)
    at buildImage (gen.js:21892)
    at Object.<anonymous> (gen.js:21888)
    at Object.<anonymous> (gen.js:21926)
    at __webpack_require__ (gen.js:20)
    at Object.exports.initBackend (gen.js:21874)
    at initBackends (gen.js:11552)
```

I can't find anything regarding this issue. The line being underlined in the generated JS file is this one:

```
stat(nextAbs, function (err, stat) {
```

Any suggestions on why I can build docker images by using node but not when being called inside of the browser? Is it even possible to start Docker containers via the browser? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it even possible to start Docker containers via the browser?

Not. The browser can't communicate with any system socket including Docker socket.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!